# Angular app transfer to version 6 error: 'Global is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

So I was hoping to transfer my MEAN stack app to Angular 6 and I set everything up and when I tried to fire up the app I got the following error in the console:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what causes this? I went to look for it in the specified package and found the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pre-6 versions of Angular the `global` variable and couple of other nodejs-specific variables like `process` etc. were faked by Angular itself in order to work properly.

So, the only way to make this working again is:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

in your `main.ts` / `polyfills.ts` or (I did not test this one, but looks also might be working)

```
import 'intl';
```

in the `polyfills.ts`

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9920 for more info.